# Scheduling Script with Crontab - SIGABRT internal error

Tags: bash, phantomjs, cron, scheduling

i wrote a Shell Script including [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) and now I wanted it to be run everyday at a particular time. I used crontab, and edited the file I get after calling

```
crontab -e
```

to include

```
56 13 * * * /home/lena/Str8ts_Project/str8ts2.bash
```

If I run the script manually it works out fine, but as soon as the script is scheduled, I get an Ubuntu Error message with the title *phantomjs crashed with SIGABRT in GI_raise()* .

So apparently something is wrong with phantomjs, but I have no idea what it could be.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 with Xfce on a Lenovo ThinkPad.

Thank you for your help.

EDIT: The Code for str8ts2.bash

```
!/bin/bash

### Create Image
phantomjs str8ts.js

### Crop and keep big image
#convert file_name.png -crop 414x419+318+712 cropped.png

###  Crop and discard big image
mogrify -crop 414x419+318+712 *.png

### change to directory for files and move png there
cd Str8tsFiles 
mv /home/lena/Str8ts_Project/*.png .
```

And the separate phantomjs file str8ts.js that is called in the beginning

```
var currentTime = new Date();
currentTime = currentTime.toDateString();
currentTime = currentTime.replace(/\s+/g, '_');
var file_name = currentTime + "str8ts.png";

var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://www.str8ts.de/', function() {
   page.render(file_name);
   phantom.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Find your default `bash` location using `which`

`which bash`

this will tell you the location of `bash`, e.g. `/bin/bash`

Add the full pathname call to `bash` into your crontab entry (notice the `-c` also)

```
56 13 * * * /bin/bash -c /home/lena/Str8ts_Project/str8ts2.bash
```

We just want to eliminate the problem being `bash` (or not) in your `crontab` entry.

Comment: This gives me the same error message as before. But I guess that means, that the problem is with phantomjs, doesn't it?